# Deleting an array of classes

Tags: c++

Would the following properly destroy everything (all appropriate destructors called and all memory freed)?

```
Class* var[50];
var[0] = new SubClass();

delete[] *var;
```

Similar to

```
Class** var = new Class*[50];
var[0] = new SubClass();

delete[] var;
```

Or should I be iterating over the array and delete each individual object (which is what I thought delete[] did).

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Class>>`

Comment: First off, does any of your codes work?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: It probably looks like it is working. But this is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @LokiAstari the second part doesn't even compile. The first is UB.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I see that. My point is just because it looks like it is working does not mean anything.

Comment: The second snippet does compile, I just had a typo in it when I was writing it to stackoverflow >;o. *edit* scratch that, two typos, wow I'm out of it =O.

Comment: Take a look at boost::ptr_vector<>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class* var[50];
var[0] = new SubClass();

delete[] *var;
```

This is undefined behavior. The proper way is

```
delete var[0]; //equivalent to delete *var;
```

If you allocate memory for all 50 elements of the array, then you have to iterate and delete each one of them. Think of it this way:

- for every `new`, you should have an associated `delete`
- for every `new[]`, you should have an associate `delete[]`
- don't mix up `new` with `delete[]` and `new[]` with `delete` as it leads to undefined behavior

Your second snippet is illegal C++.

**EDIT** As you're clearly a beginner, let's break this down a bit. Since the second snippet doesn't even compile, I'm going to focus on the first one:

```
Class* var[50];
```

This declares an array of 50 pointers to `Class`. The pointers are dangling - they are not initialized and `Class` objects aren't created.

```
var[0] = new SubClass();
```

This allocates memory for a `SubClass` object and assigns the first pointer in the array. All other pointers remain uninitialized.

```
*var;
```

returns the first element, which is a `Class*`. It's equivalent to `var[0]`.

```
delete[] *var;
```

attempts to call `delete[]` on a `Class*`, which was allocated with `new`, so it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: "Your second snippet is illegal C++." yes, I had an extra * there on the right (typo) =). So then the second one would require a loop + delete[] and the first one would only need the loop. Got it, thanks. *edit* -> "Since the second snippet doesn't even compile" again, I had a typo on the ** to the right =P. It does compile and run ;).

Comment: @user1136671: No! This answer is bad! Don't do it this way.

Comment: @DeadMG that's like saying - don't learn the intricates of C++. You don't need to know about pointers and arrays when you have vectors and smart pointers....

Comment: @Luchian: And.. you pretty much don't. More relevantly, I would never, ever, foist them on anyone who was not already an expert at using vectors and smart pointers. They are horrendously buggy and error-prone and using them brings no advantages over the class approach whatsoever, so why ever use them? It's plain wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to use a resource-managing class like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>`. This will always guarantee correct resource cleanup with no user intervention. Any C++ code which sees `delete`, `new[]` or `delete[]` used should be immediately refactored to avoid them- and `new` should have a second look taken.

Comment: This should be a comment. The proper way to clear the memory for the snippet he provided is with `delete`. You're providing an alternative, which is ok, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Luchian: The proper way to deal with memory is through classes. The fact that the OP is doing something horrendously stupid does not mean that he should not be corrected. My suggestion implements something remotely approximating what should actually written.

Comment: So instead of assuming he's learning about important C++ concepts, you jump to the conclusion that this is production code which should be corrected immediately. I disagree with this approach.

Comment: @Luchian: And if he's, say, learning the language, then let's teach him all the *super-bad practices we do our best to eliminate*, which are going to be *even worse* because he can hardly string two statements together? That's a dumb idea. People should be taught the best way to do it right away- and then, when they're masters of it, we should consider teaching them alternatives if they have any demonstrable advantage. Which this doesn't.

Comment: I'm not saying they shouldn't. But I also think they should know the basics. If someone asks you - how do you use an array?, you don't say - never ever use an array, you don't need to know what an array is, here, use a vector...

Comment: @Luchian: This is not basic. It's not basic at all. It requires so much to be used even remotely correctly that *everybody* invented a whole new paradigm to replace it. That's how terrible it is. There is nothing basic about this. Using pointers and arrays correctly is exceedingly difficult. You might as well describe building your own CPU out of transistors as "basic" or formulating a Theory of Everything.

Comment: C++ is difficult, and yet basic. Basic doesn't mean easy. Vectors are based on pointers internally. What more demonstrates how basic they are?

Comment: @Luchian: Their implementation is irrelevant. Ever heard of abstraction? You don't have to be anywhere near sufficiently competent to write `vector` to use it. And pointers are a million miles away from basic. A basic thing is simple and easy to use correctly, and difficult to get wrong. That's `vector<T>`, not `T*`.

Comment: Ok. We're clearly miles away here, I'm not going to change your mind, and you're not changing mine. We can just agree to disagree.

Comment: Honestly, I'm just reviewing the quirks of c++ memory deallocation. Not used to working with delete[]. One description translated it to for loop with deletions, so that immediately made me confused as my previous interpretation of it was what everyone stated it was on here =). Was just putting that up to validate =P. The first snippet was just a test to see if I could get away with it =). I know what a vector is and so on, so no need to go over them. I've been coding for 10 years, just not in c/c++, lol.

Comment: I never had a problem with manual memory management. I just stick to the rule that object which creates must also delete. `auto_ptr` sucks and is vulnerable to subtle bugs. C++11 still isn't wide-spread.

Comment: @doc: That doesn't account for exceptions at all.

Comment: @GManNickG what doesn't account for exceptions?

Comment: @doc: Manual memory management coupled with the "you new, you delete" principle. You *have* either use RAII/smart-pointers, or you literally turn your code into try-catch city.

Comment: @GManNickG the principle still works, you only need to take exceptions into account. Maybe a bit of controversy, but IMO in most cases, if things go wrong, programs should crash, rather than print enigmatic errors to frustrated users. Program that behaves unpredictably brings chaos.

Comment: @doc: Since when does throwing an exception mean the program is going to terminate?

Comment: This is the best solution. Full stop.

Answer (score 0):

`delete[]` is for dynamically allocated arrays. It corresponds to `new []`.

Excerpt from C++ Open Standards (3.7.4.2)

> If a deallocation function terminates by throwing an exception, the
>   behavior is undefined. The value of the first argument supplied to a
>   deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the
>   deallocation function is one supplied in the standard library, the
>   call has no effect. Otherwise, **the value supplied to operator
>   delete(void*)** in the standard library shall be one of the values
>   returned by a previous invocation of either operator **new(std::size_t)**
>   or operator new(std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) in the standard
>   library, and **the value supplied to operator delete[](void*)** in the
>   standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous
>   invocation of either operator **new[](std::size_t)** or operator
>   new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&) in the standard library.

Your first example does not use `new []` so you are not supposed to use `delete []` !!!

Answer (score -2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50;i++)delete var[i];
delete[] var;
```

Comment: -1 This is just wrong. You're deleting more elements than you assign, and you're not supposed to call delete on an array in automatic storage.